# SIGSEGV in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, shellcode

I am reading a book about exploiting, writing shellcode and vulnerability discovery. The chapter where I am now is about writing shellcode, I made an program in assembly and assembled it, but I got an Segmentation fault from the first mov instruction. The program needs to system call the execve function. This is the code after the assembling seen through objdump in att:

```
execve2:     file format elf32-i386
Disassembly of section .text:
08048080 <_start>:
 8048080:       eb 1a                   jmp    804809c <GotoCall>

08048062 <shellcode>:
 8048062:       5e                      pop     %esi
 8048063:       31 c0                   xor     %eax, %eax
 8048065:       88 46 07                mov     %al,0x7(%esi)
 8048068:       8d 1e                   lea     (%esi),%ebx
 804806a:       89 5e 08                mov     %ebx,0x8(%esi)
 804806d:       89 46 0c                mov     %eax,0xc(%esi)
 8048070:       b0 0b                   mov     $0xb,%al
 8048072:       89 f3                   mov     %esi,%ebx
 8048074:       8d 4e 08                lea     0x8(%esi),%ecx
 8048077:       8d 56 0c                lea     0xc(%esi),%edx
 804807a:       cd 80                   int     $0x80

0804807c <GotoCall>:
 804807c:       e8 e1 ff ff ff          call     8048062 <shellcode>
 8048081:       2f                      das
 8048082:       62 69 6e                bound    %ebp,0x6e(%ecx)
 8048085:       2f                      das
 8048086:       73 68                   jae      80480f0 <GotoCall+0x74>
 8048088:       4a                      dec %edx
 8048089:       41                      inc %ecx
 804808a:       41                      inc %ecx
 804808b:       41                      inc %ecx
 804808c:       41                      inc %ecx
 804808d:       4b                      dec %ebx
 804808e:       4b                      dec %ebx
 804808f:       4b                      dec %ebx
 8048090:       4b                      dec %ebx
```

At 8048065, I get an SIGSEGV error, I don't know what to change and what is wrong?

Comment: `.text` section is read only. You are trying to modify it.

Comment: How can I change that? I am not really familiar with assembly.

Comment: Jester is correct, and how you want to fix it depends in a way on how you build it. If you use gcc to link and compile you could try something like `gcc -static -Wl,-N  -nostartfiles -m32  execve2.s -o execve2` .This assumes the assemby file is `execve2.s` and the executable program you want is `execve2` . The main key is `-Wl,-N` which passes `-N` to the linker which is described as _Set the text and data sections to be readable and writable._ . If you link with _LD_ directly then just add `-N` to your _LD_ command line.

Comment: I build it with nasm and ld

Comment: My edited comment suggests adding `-N` to your `ld` command line if you use _LD_ directly to link.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reactions, I used the hex code from the obj dump to compute a shellcode in C and executed that, and it worked.